# the texture is covering holes i created when exporting fbx

Tags: texturing, export

the texture ( color or picture ) is covering holes i created, please help[image]

in the blender app everything showing correctly (in the Material Preview)
but when when viewing it in 3D viewer this problem occure

Comment: please show us more screenshots e.g. of your mesh or provide blend file

Comment: From the image, it looks like overlapping face

Comment: I think the problem in the export settings, because the texture showing correctly only when i export it as .glb